# Laravel Vue Router returns 404 page

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I am using Vue Router in my app. When user visits `''`, the `HomeComponent` should load and it does! However, when I goto `/login`, the `LoginComponent` doesn't load and the app redirects me to the 404 page. Please help.

`routes.js`

```
import HomeComponent from './components/Home.vue';
import LoginComponent from './components/auth/LoginComponent.vue';

export const routes = [
    {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: '/login', component: LoginComponent},
];
```

`app.js`

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
});
```

`routes/web.php`

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('layouts.master');
});
```

There's this `MasterComponent` where these routes load. The `HomeComponent` loads but other component don't load. Actually, it happened I when wrote `mode: 'history'` in my `app.js`! It was working fine earlier until I changed the mode to history.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just found the solution:

```
Route::get('/{vue_capture?}', function () {
    return view('layouts.master');
})->where('vue_capture', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

This helps the Laravel to capture URLs generated by Vue! That's it!

Comment: It works, but appreciate if anyone could explain why did it work?

Comment: I used this before `Route::get('/any', 'SpaController@index')->where('any', '.*');` which didn't work. It seems that adding `{}` arround any solved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

****First put this in your web.php****

```
Route::get('/{any}', [\App\Http\Controllers\TestController::class,'home'])->where('any', '.*');
```

**then in your router.js use this**
const routes = [

```
    {
        path: '/',
        component: () => import('./pages/Layout'),
        children: [
            { path: '', component: () => import('./components/DataTable') },
        ]
    },
    

];
```